# Cache Table from Remotely Hosted Database with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, caching, activerecord

I have a big `Microsoft SQL Database` in a remote host which I connect with `ActiveRecord 5` using `tiny_tds` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`. I need to make multiple queries to one `table` to find entries belonging to an object. The problem is that there are thousands of queries which takes a really long time to perform on a remote database.

Is it possible to cache the whole `table` so the queries would be performed in the local cached table to make them faster?

**Edit:** The purpose of this operation is to synchronize data from a legacy system to a newer one. The following loop is used for importing:

```rb
MsSqlDbEntity.where(deleted: nil).where.not(verified: nil).each do |entity|
  entity_import(entity)
end
```

These are the methods used:

```rb
def entity_import(ms_sql_db_entity)
  new_db_entity = NewDbEntity.new(
      # Some params from ms_sql_db_entity
  )

  sub_entity_import(ms_sql_db_entity, new_db_entity) if new_db_entity.save
end

def sub_entity_import(ms_sql_db_entity, new_db_entity)
  MsSqlDbSubEntity.where(ms_sql_db_entity_id: ms_sql_db_entity.id).each do |sub_entity|
    new_db_sub_entity = NewDbSubEntity.create(
        new_db_entity_id: new_db_entity.id,
        # Some other params
    )
  end
end
```

The `entity` and `sub_entity` have a `one-to-many` relation.

Comment: If you cache the whole table, which is very large, it will be stored in memory which would be blazing fast but expensive on resources.  You may want to checkout redis for this but it sounds like your table structure needs changing if you need to run thousands of queries.  What is the exact query chain you're using?  Are you eager-loading your query?

Comment: A  Code example is now added above. I don't think memory capacity will be an issue as this operation will probably be performed once a day outside of peak hours. Didn't realize it at first but could I just `eager_load` the `sub_entities` at the start with just one query? Furthermore, the legacy MS SQL DB should not be changed in any way.

Comment: Unsure what your "local" database is, but I would first look into a database-hosted cache that copies the data directly using technology such as a PostgreSQL foreign data wrapper.